# How to remove all google fonts in divi?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fonts

During the new GDPR (DSGVO in Germany). We have to remove all the google fonts (if loaded from google).

To do so I searched a little in the SC of Divi.

For all of you who need a quick fix.

Here is something for you're `functions.php`(child theme please)

```html
// REMOVE ALL DIVI GOOGLE FONTS FROM DIVI
function et_builder_get_google_fonts() {return array();}
function et_get_google_fonts() {return array();}
function disable_gfonts_divi() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'divi-fonts' );
wp_dequeue_style('et-builder-googlefonts');
wp_dequeue_style('et-builder-googlefonts-cached');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_gfonts_divi', 20 );
// END GOOGLE FONTS REMOVE
```

If one of you has some to add or if it could be done a little nicer please tell me.

Answer (score 6):

In recent Divi update, this theme comes with an option to enable or disable the google font.

You can get that option in Divi > theme option  > general settings.
Please go to Divi > theme option > General settings > Use Google font > Disable the option > save and check

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to disabling Google Fonts is, to **embed those fonts in your WordPress website**.

I've created a plugin for that, which solves that GDPR requirement and integrates smoothly with Divi. All you need to do is:

1. Install the plugin [GDPR Cache Scripts & Styles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gdpr-cache-scripts-styles/)
2. Activate the plugin
3. Wait 4-5 minutes for the plugin to download all fonts

Full plugin link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gdpr-cache-scripts-styles/